# display image with link from array of hashes

Tags: php

i am trying to display a list of image from some link within a array of hashes.  beside some other image from my own folder. Thanks in advance

```
    $config = [

   'gallery_name' => 'my_heading',

   'unsplash_categories' => ['array','of','category','keywords'],

   'local_images' => 

   ['folder/jpg1.jpg','folder/jpg2.jpg','folder/jpg1.jpg','folder/jpg4.jpg']

   ];
```

in HTML, what tried.

```
   <?php foreach($config as $my_config => $gallery_name): ?>

    <h1><?php echo $gallery_name; ?></h1>

    <?php endforeach ?>

    <p>  
     <?php foreach($config as $img)
     {
    foreach($img['local_images'] as $local_img)
    {
        echo "<img src='".$local_img['']."' alt=''>.<br>";
    }

    foreach($img['unsplash_categories'] as $unsplash_img)
    {
        echo "<img src='".$unsplash_img['']."' alt=''>.<br>";
    }
    }

 ?>   
 </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome on SO, Shaik.
Not clear on what you want to exactly achieve but if you just want to display the images using your `$config` as sample, you can simplify it a bit to something like this:

```
<h1><?= $config["gallery_name"]; ?></h1>

<p> 
    <?php
    foreach($config['local_images'] as $local_img)
    {
        echo "<img src='" . $local_img . "' alt=''>.<br>";
    }

    //same for unsplash_categories...
    ?>   
</p>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. just to be more clear, I like to add four image which is an array from my folder and another four image which is also image but from link